# iostream alone gives me 457 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to both C++ and Visual Studio 2015 and already have 457 errors in my first program.

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

this simple piece of "hello world" code gave me 457 errors so I started experimenting and found out that even this

```
    #include <iostream>
```

by itself gives me all those errors. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Please paste some of the errors

Comment: Did you give your source file a `.c` extension?

Comment: the source file has a .cpp extension

Comment: the errors are all in russian and I cant really translate them

Comment: Perhaps you selected the wrong type of project. Make sure it was a win32 console application.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just paste them somewhere.

Comment: не удается открыть источник файл "float.h" Проект1 d:\Программы\VC\include\cfloat 7 
не удается открыть источник файл "math.h" Проект1 d:\Программы\VC\include\cmath 12 
глобальная область видимости не содержит "acosf" Проект1 d:\Программы\VC\include\cmath 661 
глобальная область видимости не содержит "asinf" Проект1 d:\Программы\VC\include\cmath 661 
глобальная область видимости не содержит "atanf" Проект1 d:\Программы\VC\include\cmath 662 
глобальная область видимости не содержит "atan2f"these are the errors

Comment: I opened an empty project in c++

Comment: I just tried running it as a win32 console application and it gave me all those errors but with huge line skips inbetween

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your Visual Studio

Comment: Please paste your errors, using the code formatting button, **in the question itself**. Use the "edit" feature please!

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: it does indeed matter where errors are posted. If they are in the comments they are unreadable, and if they are on an external pasteboard then the question is not self-contained. Either way, the question remains off-topic and may be closed.

Comment: have you forgotten `#include "stdafx.h"`? add the errors messages

Comment: The code is correct, so you must have a problem with project settings or a bad install. Look at the first error message: if it is not clear what it is saying, then try pasting it into a google search.  (If there are a huge number of errors, I just look at the first one. The rest often go away after I fix the first.)

Comment: There's not a whole lot of info here anyone could use to help you. If you're on windows 10, I'd recomend looking into the windows ubuntu bash shell and compiling with g++ in the terminal

Comment: Drop C++ and do Java instead :D

Comment: The possible problem is invalid VS installation. I have both `cmath` and `math.h` in `%install_dir%\VC\include`. Do you have both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your hello world program is correct. See [here](http://cpp.sh/4u3h)

What you may want to look into is if PATH environment variable on your Windows Machine is set correctly.

Alternatively, you may want to compile the program in Windows shell/powershell and see if that is working for you.

May I also recommend using [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) installer and get started right away with your compilation & execution.